# Using CTRL +V in Mail app on Mac Os X

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, email, macos

I'm using **Mail** client that's built-in into the system (Yosemite). I've decided that I want to use CTRL+V, CTRL+C and similar instead of CMD because I work half of the day with Windows and it's impossible for me to easily switch off my habits every half a day. I've considered 2 options:

- final switch between CTRL and CMD which had a lot of consequences that I didn't wanted to tackle
- switching on Shorcuts option available at System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and adding here any "special" shortcuts on per app basis.

I've used 2nd option. This generally works fine. I've added things like **Copy**, **Cut**, **Undo Paste** and so on mostly mimicking what I have on my Windows machines. And everything seems to be working fine except one small detail "**CTRL+V**" paste. It only works as a PASTE until the email I'm creating fits on page. When there's a lot of text.. the **CTRL+V** becomes **Page Down** button. It's like **CTRL+V** in the Mail app is hardcoded to be Page Down and the shorcuts seems to be working fine until **CTRL+V** is able to actually behave as Page Down then it stops working.

How do I disable Page Down **(CTRL+V)** behaviour as described above?

Comment: It's easier to get used to the distinction than try to fight it, long-term.

Comment: Instead of using key strokes, cut, copy & paste can also be executed from the Edit menu.

Comment: I switch daily between Linux and Mac. Trust me, it is the completely opposite of impossible to switch. I rarely make a mistake

Comment: I am not fighting. I just want to use what I want to use. I have virtual machines on mac and those use ctrl+c/v an then mac uses cmd+c. Then another computer next to me users ctrl+c. I switch a lot between different systems. I want things to work my way. It seems like a bug to me in Mail.app.

Comment: Control+V is no bug; it's an Emacs and general UNIX shortcut for page down. Apple implemented it so you can navigate text easily. ([here's a list of all shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201247))

Comment: Ok. So the question is how can it be disabled.. Since I've overwritten the Shorcut and it's behaviour is now less than expected.

Comment: See my answer on [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228523/microsoft-outlook-does-not-properly-handle-redefined-paste-keyboard-shortcut/229729#229729)

Answer (score 5):

I run into same issue: At work I have to use Windows and at home I use a Mac. I'm sick of having different shortcuts for these basic tasks. Here is my solution for it:

Go to your User folder on your Mac and open the Library directory.

Here you create a "KeyBindings" folder.

Then navigate into that folder:
(Your User folder)/Library/KeyBindings/

Create a file "DefaultKeyBinding.dict" with following lines:

```
"^v" = "paste:";
"^c" = "copy:";
"^x" = "cut:";
"^z" = "undo:";
```

Save everything and restart your Mac.

Now, you will have CTRL + x/c/v/z working like it is on a Windows machine.

This will change the behaviour for page down as requested by MadBoy.

Comment: You just saved my life. That was itching since 3 years, and you finally gave me the only fix that works !

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier and more effective way to do this: go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard tab and click the "Modifier Keys..." button.

From there, you can set the Control key to behave like the Command key:

[image]

Comment: I've already mentioned in my main post I don't want to do that. This changes behaviour of so many things it's not an option for me.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work and doesn't fix the issue (which is related to Cmd+V, but not other Cmd+X bindings...)

Answer (score 2):

[**Karabiner**](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)

This will do exactly what you're looking for, I think this is the setting you're looking for too.

[image]

Comment: I got used to CMD +V although I do get some frustrations from time to time when things don't go as planned.

Answer (score 1):

Create or edit the file: ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.Dict (may need to create the folders as well) to contain the text:

```
{"^v" = noop:;}
```

You will then need to close and re-open the programs that you were have problems with.