# Microsoft Outlook does not properly handle redefined "Paste" keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, macos, ms-office

I've been a windows user for a long time, and I hate the <kbd>⌘</kbd> shortcuts for stuff. Since I only use my Mac for work stuff, I figured I'd just redefine the App Shortcuts from the keyboard menu so I could use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, etc.

This works fine in almost every app I've tried, except Microsoft Outlook. There <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works, but <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does not. I can copy selected text just fine, but Paste exhibits some weird behavior.

Hitting <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> causes the cursor to jump several lines down and scroll the e-mail. I can continue hitting <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> until the cursor reaches the *very* end of the e-mail, at which point I can now paste again. The entire time, the menu shows the correct shortcut:

[image: Outlook Edit Menu]

The Edit menu does not flash (and no other menu flashes either) signaling that a keyboard shortcut in that menu has been pressed until the cursor is at the very end of the document.

And I have everything set up correctly in keyboard settings:
[image: keyboard settings]

Unsurprisingly, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> also doesn't work because that's not a valid shortcut anymore.

Has anybody found a solution for this issue?

Edit: Turns out it's not just Outlook that has this issue. Several OSX applications will view <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> as a "scroll down" operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

Create DefaultKeyBinding.dict under ~/Library/KeyBindings (Create KeyBindings folder if it doesn't exists)  Then paste the contents below into that file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
          <key>^v</key>
          <string>noop:</string>
  </dict>
  </plist>
```

Alternately, you can use the following, non-XML syntax (this is the entire contents of the file, and any other keybindings would go inside the curly braces):

```
{
    "^v" = noop:;
}
```

Restart Outlook, and all other affected programs, and ctrl + v should no longer scroll down.

Comment: Brilliant, wish I'd thought of that! I'm editing your answer to include the alternate way I did using DefaultKeyBinding.dict though.