# Stop Ctrl+v doing page down in mail and safari apps (Mojave)

Tags: keyboard, safari, mail.app, mojave

I have same problem as [Using CTRL +V in Mail app on Mac Os X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156211/using-ctrl-v-in-mail-app-on-mac-os-x) but in Mojave and for more apps.

I have Ctrl+v setup as paste in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts. This works fine in many apps but in the mail and safari apps it does a page down. If I hit Ctrl+v at the bottom of the text window then it works as a paste, meaning I can paste stuff into a text box but only at the bottom. How can I stop it doing this page down?

The solutions in the other questions involved mapping the command key to the Ctrl key using a feature that I can't see in Mojave. In any case this is not acceptable as I want to be able to use the command key in other situations.

Comment: Hey! As in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/156261)  answer, Can you see "Modifier Keys" in system preferences -> Keyboard -> keyboard tab?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228523/microsoft-outlook-does-not-properly-handle-redefined-paste-keyboard-shortcut/229729#229729

Comment: Thanks, this does fix my issue and may be what I end up with but ideally I'd also like to be able to use the command button as well.

Comment: Hey if you're talking about second link, it stops scroll down behaviour of ctrl. so cmd should retain its purpose. I wrote first comment before reefing your last para. 
also close the question once your problem is solved.

Comment: Having used it for a few minutes I ran into the problem that when I use my remote Linux machine the control key now does nothing as linux isn't designed to work with the command key. I could reconfigure the whole linux machine but I don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create or edit the file: ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.Dict
(may need to create the folders as well) to contain the text:

```
{"^v" = noop:;}
```

You will then need to close and re-open the programs that you were have problems with.

Comment: This does not work for Ventura 13.3 Notes application.